# Preventing SQL Injections

Tags: database, sql, api

In a EE plugin if I construct a sql statement based on passed in parameters and use a EE->db->query($sql) call does the query function prevent SQL Injections or do I need to change my code to use some other query function to bind parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always scrub any user input before it gets to your query.

The first thing you should do is run and input variables through the input class.
i. e. `$var = ee()->input->post('my_var', TRUE)`
this will run the XSS filter on the data.

Then when you use it in your sql:
(this used to be a thing, but I can't find in the EE3 docs, they may of rolled it into the query or get  function)

```
$var =ee()->db->escape_str($var)
```